# Grid In Polymer Web App

Tags: css, html, grid-layout, polymer, web-component

Google is promoting (kind of) [a 48px grid for android apps](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html).

Is there a simple/idiomatic way to implement horizontal/vertical flow in my web app? It uses polymer paper web components almost exclusively. 
My biggest problem at the moment is [getting paper-checkboxes to behave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992725/styling-polymer-web-components).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution when working with a grid in polymer
is to use the app-grid helper class.

[Polymer app-grid Documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-grid)